# Force on a Charge

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, forces, charge

I apologize, as this question is quite basic.

Suppose we have a point mass of mass $m$. Suppose it is at position $r(t)$ at time $t$. Then the magnitude of the force on this mass is $\ddot r(t) m$ at time $t$.

My question is, suppose we have a point charge of charge $q$. Suppose it is at position $r(t)$ at time $t$. Is the magnitude of the force on this mass $\ddot r(t) q$? If this is not the case, what is the correct formula for the force involving $r(t)$?

Comment: Is the charge in an EM field?

Comment: So the question seems to be incomplete, but let me state a couple of things. A stationary charge does NOT exert/experience a force on itself. A charge can exert a force on itself if it accelerates (but probably beyond the scope of what you're asking). And finally a charge can experience a force if another charge is present or if it's in an EM field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Newton's second law, the net force $\mathbf F$ acting on any particle is equal to
$$\mathbf F=m\mathbf a=m\ddot{\mathbf r}$$

This is true whether or not the particle is charged.

It is not true that 
$$\mathbf F=q\mathbf a=q\ddot{\mathbf r}$$
i.e. you don't exchange the mass for charge when we have a charged particle being acted upon by a force. Mass and charge are two separate things (notice how the units don't work out in your proposed equation as well).

If the force depends on the charge, then the charge comes into play. But it does so because the mechanism of the force depends on the charge, not because the charge determines the relation between force and acceleration. For example, if the charge is in a uniform static electric field $\mathbf E$, then it will feel a force, by definition of the electric field, of $$\mathbf F=q\mathbf E$$
But by Newton's second law it must be true that
$$\mathbf F=m\ddot{\mathbf r}$$
So we will have 
$$\ddot{\mathbf r}=\frac qm\mathbf E$$

Notice how we assumed that Newton's law can be applied to this particle. The particle's charge just determines what that force will be in this particular instance, but in general you always have $\mathbf F=m\ddot{\mathbf r}$